# Uknei Lecha Chaveir- let the pen be your chavrusa

Tags: sources-mekorot, pirke-avot-ethicsof, hacham-ovadia-yosef

In the article ["How to Build Enthusiasm in Learning" by Rabbi Yosef Peretz](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=115&seriesid=11#:%7E:text=Write%20a%20Book,this%20for%20everyone.), it writes at point #12 the following:

> Rabbi Ovadia Yosef zt'l said on the mishna in [pirkei avot "kenei lecha chaver"](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A7%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B5%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%97%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B5%D7%A8&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) - "kenei" means also quill, i.e. let the pen be your chavrusa.

Rav Ovadia Yosef explains that the sentence kenei lecha chaver can also mean that your pen is your chavrusa.

- Are there others that share this interpretation (sources welcome)

- Where does Rav Ovadia Yosef write this?

Comment: I've heard that in the name of others too.

Comment: Other citations are also very welcome :)

Comment: To be precise Kaneh means 'reed' like a reed-pen. A quill is a feather from a bird

Comment: @kouty It's available on Sefaria. Do you know in which siman this can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. Ovadia has said this in various drashot and shiurim that he has given. Here is how it was transcribed from a drasha, collected in a volume of mussar called *Ma'adanei Ha-Melekh*:

> הכרתי תלמידי חכמים גאונים שלא הורגלו בצעירותם לכתוב, וכשהיו אחר כך בגדלותם כותבים, היו יוצאים הדברים מסורסים מהופכים ומבולבלים, הם בעצמם לא היה נוח להם במה שכתבו ולא היו שבעי רצון, כיון שלא הורגלו
>
> אומרים 'וקָנה לך חבר', בקמץ. כשאתה לומד לבד הדברים אינם ברורים, אתה
> לומד עם חבר, אתה מסביר לו והוא מסביר לך, אתה מתווכח אתו
>
> העט שלך הוא חברך והוא מתווכח אתך, אמנם אתה מכתיב לו, לא הוא מושל עליך,
> אבל התרחבות הדברים מרחיבה את דעתך ומעמידה אותך על האמת, כשמתחיל לכתוב
> רואה אין דמיון בין זה לזה, וכך הוא מגיע באמת לגופו של הלכה. ולכן כמה
> זה חשוב שאדם ירגיל את עצמו לכתוב
>
> I knew students of genius scholars who didn't write in their youth, and when they later grew up and started writing, the words would come out garbled, distorted and confused. They themselves weren't comfortable with what they wrote and weren't satisfied because they were not used to it.
>
> They say 'acquire [kanei] for yourself a friend', with
> a *kamatz* vowel under the word acquire [meaning quill]. When you study alone things
> are not clear. But when you study with a friend, you explain to him
> and he explains to you, and you argue with him.
>
> Your pen is your friend and he argues with you. Even though you
> dictate to him what to write, he does not rule over you, but the
> expansion of words expands your knowledge and positions you toward the
> truth. When one starts writing, one sees that there is no similarity
> between one another, and thus he really reaches the body of Halakha.
> That is why it is so important that a person gets used to writing.

And here are his words, also in *Ma'adanei Ha-Melekh*, from another drasha:

> כל אחד ישתדל כפי כוחו להעמיק בתורה, וגם יקיים בעצמו 'וקָנה לך חבר', זהו העט שיהיה חברך. אם אין לך חברותא, כתוב את הדברים וחזור עליהם. בדרך כלל אדם שמבין היטב את הסוגיא יכול לשכחה אחרי כמה ימים, אך לא כן אם ירשמנה יזכור בדיוק את כולה
>
> Everyone should strive as hard as he can to delve deeper into the Torah. He will also fulfill by himself the mitzvah 'acquire for yourself a friend.' This is the pen that will be your friend. If you don't have a ḥevruta, write the words down and repeat them. Usually, a person who understands well the sugya can forget it after a few days, but not if he writes it down. He will remember it exactly in its entirety.

Comment: Thank you for bringing the source from R'Ovadia Yosef. Interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The [Kav Hayashar, ch. 53](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40032&st=&pgnum=153&hilite=) already wrote along those lines:

> "קנה לך חבר כמשמעו וגם רמז על הקולמוס יהיה לך חבר שתכתוב מה שתחדש..."

Translation: "Keneh Lecha Chaver, in the plainest meaning, but also a hint that the pen will be your friend, as you will write down your new ideas..."

A similar idea was also [written](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20297&pgnum=254) in Siddur Ha'Ariz"l by [Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91), one of the earlier members of the Chassidic movement.

A number of Chabad sources bring such an idea in the name of the first Rebbe of Chabad, Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liadi, for example [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43302&st=&pgnum=89).

As for the Rav Ovadyah, I'm not sure he wrote it anywhere, but it seems to have been an idea he had stated several times, as can be found in [this](https://www.kikar.co.il/haredim-news/126082) interview with him, not long before he died.

Answer (score 3):

Also refer to the Likkutei Halachos written by the talmid muvhak (chief disciple) of Rav Nachman MiBreslov - [Rabbi Nosson Sternhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_of_Breslov)

He writes [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Halakhot%2C_Orach_Chaim%2C_Laws_of_the_New_Moon.7.55.1?vhe=Likutei_Halachot:_Orach_Chaim_2&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as follows:

> וְזֶה עֲשֵׂה לְךָ רַב וּקְנֵה לְךָ חָבֵר וּמוּבָא בַּסְּפָרִים שֶׁמְּרַמֵּז עַל הַקָּנֶה וְהַקֻּלְמוֹס שֶׁהוּא חָבֵר לְהַתַּלְמִיד חָכָם שֶׁיִּתְקַיְּמוּ דִּבְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה עַל-יְדֵי זֶה.
>
> And this (mishna) - "Make for yourself a Rav and acquire for yourself a friend"; it is brought in the seforim that it hints to the acquisition of a quill which is a friend to a wise student that fulfils divrei Torah through this...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online http: on this website it brings from rav ovadia in a letter to a rosh yeshiva at the beggining off the zman

Comment: Thank you. If you could put the relevant section into the answer, that would be very nice!

Comment: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01528_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2